# Can I store a wildcard string in active record and expect to match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to store a string with a wildcard in an active record database, perhaps like this:

```
@food.name = "*burger"
```

and then search like this:

```
Food.find_by_name ("foo_burger")
```

and get a match.

Obviously this doesn't work, or I wouldn't be asking.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you not use `where` with `like '%_burger'` and save `burger`?

Comment: The issue is that the wildcard is in the database.  When the request comes in, I don't know how what to strip off to create a wildcard for a query.  There are hundreds of burgers out there and I want to match all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should checkout some `gems` for matching your names. Give a try to `squeel` and `ransack` gem